# Binding Two Variables Together

Tags: javascript, data-binding

```
qpo.activeGame.teams.blue
qpo.blue
```

Above are two references/identifiers. I create an object and have the first identifier (qpo.activeGame.teams.blue) point to it. Then, I want to have the second identifier (qpo.blue) point to the same object (which will change, and both identifiers need to keep pointing to the newest version of that object.)

Do I achieve this like this?

```
qpo.blue = qpo.activeGame.teams.blue
```

Or, is it more complicated?

I apologize for my lack of a computer science background. (Is data binding even the right term for this?)

Comment: If two variables (or object properties) reference the same object, then changes to the "innards" of that object will be visible via either variable (or property). However, there is no way to make one variable "follow" another variable so that it always has the same value. It would help to provide a more useful answer if you would describe a couple of situations that you are interested in.

Comment: Code readability. The first identifier is informative but long. The second is short but not informative.

Comment: So, are you saying that as long as no NEW object is instantiated, the code I have will work?

Comment: If your first identifier is subsequently the target of an assignment operation (`qpo.activeGame.teams.blue = something;`) then the other variable will have to be explicitly updated too. There's no way to "hook them together".

Comment: But if all that happens is `qpo.blue.foo = "bar";` and stuff like that, then it will work.

Comment: Cool. I'd suggest posting as answer so I can accept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot cause two variables to become "married" so that an assignment to one is effectively an assignment to the other. (There's one weirdness that could possibly be construed as that situation, but it's not something you'd ever do in practice.)

However, if two variables (or object properties) refer to the same object, then changes to the constituent properties and sub-properties of that object *will* be visible via either reference. That's because a reference to an object is, in fact, just a reference. Two variables sharing the same reference value both refer to the same single object.

Comment: Curiously, it's far more common on Stackoverflow to see questions about why two references to the same object both reflect property changes in the object.